# How to echo only one parameter with union all

Tags: php, mysql

I have to database tables. I want to print union all names from both tables and if there is more than one name appears then print it only once and make it red for example.
My PHP:

```
<?php
    include 'verification/verify_form_details.php';

    $result5 = getUsers();
    if (!$result5) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
    }   
    while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5))
    {  
        $username = $row5['username'] ;
        echo '<ul>';    
        echo"<li>". $username ."</li>";
        echo '</ul>';   
    }           
?>
```

And my query:

```
function getUsers()
{
    global $con;
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM `user_project` 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT username FROM `user`";
    return mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
}
```

How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your query to group by user name

```
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM 
            (
            SELECT username FROM `user_project` 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT username FROM `user`
            )
            GROUP BY username";
```

Also if you want to get number of appearance so that you can  make  red those having multiple occurrence

```
$sql = "SELECT username, count(username) FROM 
                (
                SELECT username FROM `user_project` 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT username FROM `user`
                )
                GROUP BY username";
```

Comment: NIce, it works as I want it to, but why do I have an empty line? First line of me new table is empty name with count of 1

Comment: Do you have an empty username in the table?

Comment: Oh nvm, it was empty line inside user table, I just removed it

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM 
        (
        SELECT username FROM `user_project` 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT username FROM `user`
        )
        GROUP BY username";
```

add 'distinct' to this